# Method of one class can't access the int variable of same class

Tags: c++

**Note:** Please stop downvoting...i tried a lot but it was just a Typo which i couldn't find.

I have a class `Node` which have certain methods and variables. I am trying to access a variable `int state` from two methods i.e. `void setState()` and `int getState(void)`. The first method is able to set the value of `state` but the second method (i.e. `int getState(void)`) gives an error.

**`Node.h`**

```
class Node{
private:
    vector<Wire*> inputs;       
    vector<Wire*> outputs;      
    int state;                  

public:

    void addOutput(Wire *a);                
    void addInput(Wire *a);             


    Node* getInput(unsigned int i);     
    Node* getOutput(unsigned int i);        

    void setState(int st);              
    int  getState(void);            


};
```

**`main()`**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Node* b=new Node(INPUT, "B");
    Node* a=new Node(INPUT, "A");
    Node* Cin=new Node(INPUT, "Cin");
    Node* d=new Node(XOR, "D");
    Wire* w=new Wire(a,d);
    d->addInput(w);
    a->addOutput(w);

    vector<Node*> inputs;
    vector<Node*> outputs;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<inputs.size();j++) {
            inputs[j]->setState(rand()%2);
            cout << inputs[j]->getState(); // THIS LINE IS GIVING THE ERROR
        }

    }
    return 0;

}
```

**`node.cpp`**

```
void Node::addInput(Wire *a)
{
    inputs.push_back(a);
}

void Node::addOutput(Wire *a)
{
    outputs.push_back(a);
}

string Node::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void Node::setState(int st)         
{
    state = st;

    cout<<"\nState set to: "<<state;
}
int  getState(void)
{
    //return 0;
    return state;

}
```

**Error:** error: ‘state’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: `int  getState(void)`
should be `int Node::getState(void)`

Comment: `Node::getState(void)` you forgot `Node::` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple typo:

```
int Node::getState(void)
{
    //return 0;
    return state;

}
```

will fix it. (The member variable `state` is only assessible within methods of the `Node` class). You're currently defining a function `int getState()` in the global namespace which is perfectly legal until you attempt to refer to the class data member. That's why the compile error is a little cryptic.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int  getState(void)
```

to

```
int  Node::getState(void)
```

The former declares a new free function, and members of `Node` aren't directly in its scope.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from that you forgot to specify class name in the definition of member function getState (there must be

```
int  Node::getState(void)
{
    //return 0;
    return state;

}
```

) your code is invalid. First of all the class has no constructor with two parameters. SO the compiler shall issue an error for statements like this

```
Node* b=new Node(INPUT, "B");
```

Also you are trying to use the subscript operator for empty vector inputs (inputs[j]->setState(rand()%2); )

```
vector<Node*> inputs;
vector<Node*> outputs;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    for(unsigned int j=0;j<inputs.size();j++) {
        inputs[j]->setState(rand()%2);
        cout << inputs[j]->getState(); // THIS LINE IS GIVING THE ERROR
    }

}
```

That is the inner loop will be never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Just indicate which class `int getState(void)` belongs to, with `int Node::getState(){return state;}`